# adding timer variable asp

Tags: time, average

Hi I'm looking for a way to add together and do a average of values in a time format.

if I only do a simple '+' it puts the time back to back :

```
totalconvavgtalkduration = ((CSQ1convavgtalkduration)+(CSQ2convavgtalkduration))
```

Instead of getting something like

```
 3:02:00
```

I get

```
 3:00:000:02:00
```

Comment: Can you add which programming language you are using as this is key to helping you.

Comment: this is for a asp page

Comment: VBScrit to be more precise